# How to route http Get via tunnel in Go?

Tags: ssh, go

I have a ssh tunnel to my server (via port: 9998). I want my http GET/POST requests to be routed through this port in Go. In java I would specify the DsocksProxyHost and DsocksProxyPort. I am looking for a similar option in Go. Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: If I have time I'll try to write up an answer but I haven't really dealt with this type of thing for awhile so might not be able to. Anyway, my advice is to checkout `http.Client`. It has a property called `Transport` which is an interface of type `RoundTripper`. I believe it will be necessary for you to provide an implementation of this.

Comment: Adding to what @evanmcdonnal said, your implementation of `http.RoundTripper` can be [`http.Transport`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Transport), with the `Dial` field set to the returned `Dial` function of [`proxy.SOCKS5`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/proxy#SOCKS5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the information provided in the above comments, here is a working example on how to tunnel HTTP requests through a SOCKS proxy:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/net/proxy"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://example.com"
    socksAddress := "localhost:9998"

    socks, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", socksAddress, nil, &net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Dial:                socks.Dial,
            TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        },
    }

    res, err := client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", string(content))
}
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: If I set my Firefox to connect to this socks proxy how can I use dinamically destination of URL? from the browser... thx

Comment: Can I use this pattern to make the local socks proxy connect to an remote "exit" proxy?