# How to bind an http.Client in Go to an IP Address

Tags: http, go, ip

I have a client machine with multiple NICs, how do I bind an http.Client in Go to a certain NIC or to a certain SRC IP Address?

Say you have some very basic http client code that looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    webclient := &http.Client{}
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.google.com", nil)
    httpResponse, _ := webclient.Do(req)
    defer httpResponse.Body.Close()
}
```

Is there a way to bind to a certain NIC or IP?

Comment: Certain NICs can talk to certain VLANs, so I need to specify which local address is used.  WGET for example, supports this with the --bind-address=ADDRESS command line flag.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33681662/), you need to set the `http.Client.Transport` field. Setting it to an instance of `net.Transport` allows you to specify which `net.Dialer` you want to use. `net.Dialer` then allows you to specify the local address to make connections from.

Example:

```
localAddr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip", "<my local address>")
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

// You also need to do this to make it work and not give you a 
// "mismatched local address type ip"
// This will make the ResolveIPAddr a TCPAddr without needing to 
// say what SRC port number to use.
localTCPAddr := net.TCPAddr{
    IP: localAddr.IP,
}


webclient := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
            LocalAddr: &localTCPAddr,
            Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
            DualStack: true,
        }).DialContext,
        MaxIdleConns:          100,
        IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a fully working example that incorporates the answer from Tim.  I also broke out all of the nested pieces to make it easier to read and learn from.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    localAddr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip", "10.128.64.219")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    localTCPAddr := net.TCPAddr{
        IP: localAddr.IP,
    }

    d := net.Dialer{
        LocalAddr: &localTCPAddr,
        Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
    }

    tr := &http.Transport{
        Proxy:               http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        Dial:                d.Dial,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }

    webclient := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

    // Use NewRequest so we can change the UserAgent string in the header
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.google.com:80", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    res, err := webclient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("DEBUG", res)
    defer res.Body.Close()

    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", string(content))
}
```