# Golang http connection from a specific source port

Tags: http, go

I am trying to connect with a remote http server to test some middlebox.
I need to be able to specify the connection source port because the middlebox software does not allow wildwcards yet in the five tuple specification for the redirection rules ... so

How can I create a http request specifying the source port?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: [Refer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33768929/2285935)

Comment: Your error isn't a Go problem, `159.107.45.245:12345` is in use, so you can't bind to it again (this is why outgoing connections always use a random system assigned port number.)

Comment: You are right ... there was a service going up and down using the port ... so It been difficult to see it ..